# Krajee file-input submit files on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-io

I am using this plugin for bootstrap to upload files which is stored in a form with submit button

http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/

My question is - 
a) is there a method or something to either check if there are files in the dropZone that are still not uploaded and notify a user after he submits a form that he didn't uploaded the files

b) is there a method that will trigger the upload when the submit button is fired?

Now it looks like this - if I submit my form it wont upload the files and just pass the form, I have to manually click upload files then submit the form
Maybe some of you came across this issue cause I am not able to figure it out myself due to poor documentation.

Comment: sadly none :) well its dead by now

Answer (score 2):

I found a work around for this issue.

```
<input id="input-photos" name="Photos" multiple type="file" class="file-loading">
```

1. Define a global variable in Javascript:

```js
var formData = new FormData();
```

2. Append the selected files to `formData` on `filePreUpload` action.

```js
 $('#input-photos').on('filebatchpreupload', function(event, data, previewId, index) {
 var form = data.form, files = data.files, extra = data.extra,
  response = data.response, reader = data.reader;

 $.each(files, function (key, value) {
  if(value != null){
   formData.append("Photos", value, value.name);
  }
 }); });
```

3. On form submission append all form fields and post the form through ajax.

```js
$('#yourForm').submit(function() {
 $('#input-photos').fileinput('upload');
 var model_data = $("#yourForm").serializeArray();
 $.each(model_data,function(key,input){
  formData.append(input.name,input.value);
 });
 $.ajax({
  url: "@Url.Action("Save", "Home")",
  type: "POST",
  datatype: "json",
  data: formData,
  processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
  contentType: false,   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
  success: (function (result){
   window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
  }),
  error: function (xhr) {
   alert("Error: " + xhr.statusText);
  }
 });
 return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Validation of required property for form based upload (non ajax) scenario, which will enforce files to be selected and required before upload. This scenario includes custom form submit and reset buttons for upload (and default upload and remove buttons are hidden). The upload will force a file to be selected and required - else a validation error as set in msgRequired will be shown.

Try it:-
https://plugins.krajee.com/file-count-validation-demo#required-non-ajax-1