# Customize "Submit" button [krajee's File Input]

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, file-io

I have a classic form and I use Fileinput in the form. Submit button, I want to use it with the form's own button.

Is it possible to cancel the plugin's `upload` button and use the form's submit button?

- [Demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emresaracoglu/f97humsd/)
- [File-Input Usage Methods](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#usage-modes)

```js
$("#images").fileinput({
  language: "tr",
  uploadAsync: false,
  allowedFileExtensions: ["jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg"],
  showBrowse: false,
  browseOnZoneClick: true,
  uploadUrl: "img.php?v=1",
  elErrorContainer: '#kv-error-2',
  showCaption: false,
  showUpload: false,
  showCancel: false,
  overwriteInitial: false,
  uploadExtraData: function(previewId, index) {
    var data = {
      project_id: $("#firstname").val(),
      discussion_title: $("#username").val(),
    };
    return data;
  },
}).on('filebatchpreupload', function(event, data, id, index) {
  $('#kv-success-2').html('<h4>Upload Status</h4><ul></ul>').hide();
}).on('filebatchuploadsuccess', function(event, data) {
  // 
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.4.5/css/fileinput.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.4.5/js/plugins/piexif.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.4.5/js/plugins/sortable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.4.5/js/plugins/purify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.4.5/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.4.5/js/locales/LANG.js"></script>




<form action="/action_page.php" style="padding:20px">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br><br>
  <input id="input-b1" name="input-b1" type="file" class="file"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Krajee file-input submit files on form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075527/krajee-file-input-submit-files-on-form-submit)

Comment: @Alex I know. I tried it but it doesn't work. may be suitable for the older version.