# Trying to send files to the controller using Ajax and puglin Krajee file input in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am having trouble sending multiple data types to laravel controller using ajax,
can someone help me ?.

**What do I need to work in the code below:
send the text inputs, including the pdf file, via ajax to the controller,
using the submit button instead of the krajee plugin button**

I'm using:
**AJAX**,
**JQUERY**,
**LARAVEL**,
**KRAJEE INPUT FILE PUGLIN** https://plugins.krajee.com/file-input

My code is based on this:

[Krajee file-input submit files on form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075527/krajee-file-input-submit-files-on-form-submit)

**DD return from controller:**

```
array:5 [
  "_token" => "TfazfXdJuIIyNe59MNx8DfJJvCl7ePkj66jsW6Vl"
  "cliente_titulo" => "teste name"
  "cliente_data" => "2021/12"
  "cliente_cliente" => "Test"
  "cliente_condominio" => "Test"
]
```

**CONTROLLER CODE FUNCTION:**

```
public function create(Request $request){

  dd($request->all());     
     
}
```

**HTML CODE :**

```
<form method="POST"  id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {{ csrf_field() }}

  <input id="cliente_titulo" type="text" class="form-control" name="cliente_titulo" >

  <input id="cliente_cliente" type='text'  name="cliente_cliente" class="form-control 
   autocomplete="off" >

  <input id="cliente_condominio" type="text" class="form-control"  name="cliente_condominio">
  
  <input id="cliente_pdf" name="cliente_pdf" type="file" class="file-loading"  
   enctype="multipart/form-data" data-allowed-file-extensions='["pdf"]' >
   
   <button id="confirm-create" type="submit"  class="btn btn-success" >CREATE</button>
                 
</form>
```

**JS CODE:**

```
<script>

var formData = new FormData();
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    
    $("#cliente_pdf").on('filebatchpreupload', function(event, data, previewId, index) {
        var form = data.form, files = data.files, extra = data.extra,
            response = data.response, reader = data.reader;

        $.each(files, function (key, value) {
            if(value != null){
                formData.append("pdf", value, value.name);
            }
        }); 
    });

    $('#upload').submit(function() {

    $('#cliente_pdf').fileinput({
    language: "pt-BR",
    allowedFileExtensions: 'pdf',
    maxFileCount: 1,
    });
    var model_data = $("#upload").serializeArray();
    $.each(model_data,function(key,input){
        formData.append(input.name,input.value);
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "create",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
        contentType: false,   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
        success: function (data){
            console.log('certo');
        },
        error: function (data){
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

**ATTEMPTS:**

**HTML:**

```
<form method="POST"  id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="cliente_titulo" type="text" class="form-control" name="cliente_titulo" >
    <input id='cliente_data' type='text' class="form-control"   name="cliente_data" autocomplete="off" >
    <input id="cliente_cliente" type='text'  id_cliente="" value=""  name="cliente_cliente" class="form-control {{ url_ativa('visualizarLogin')  }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#full-colored-cliente" autocomplete="off" >
    <input id="cliente_condominio" type="text" class="form-control"  name="cliente_condominio" >
    <input id="cliente_pdf" name="pdf" type="file"  enctype="multipart/form-data" data-allowed-file-extensions='["pdf"]' required>
    <button id="confirm-create" type="submit"  class="btn btn-success" style="display:none"><strong>CRIAR FLIPBOOK</strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#cliente_pdf").fileinput({
            language: "pt-BR",
            uploadUrl: "{{ url('create') }}", 
            uploadAsync: true,
            allowedFileExtensions: 'pdf',
            maxFileCount: 1,
            showUpload: false,
            purifyHtml: true,       
            uploadExtraData: function(){
                return {
                    _token: $("input[name='_token']").val();
                }
            },
            fileActionSettings: {
            showUpload: false, 

            },
        });


        $('#upload_form').on('submit',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData($(this).get(0));
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'create',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,             
            data:formData,
            beforeSend: function(){
                console.log('enviando');
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log('sucesso');
            },
     
            cache: false,      
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            error:function(){
                console.log('erro');
            }
        });
    });
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FlipbookController {
  public function create(Request $request){
        
    dd($request->file());
           or
    dd($request->all());
           or
    dd($request->files());
            or
    dd($request->file('pdf'));
  }
}
```

o unico que obetive resultado foi o

```
dd($request->all());
```

**DD return from controller:**

```
array:5 [
  "_token" => "TfazfXdJuIIyNe59MNx8DfJJvCl7ePkj66jsW6Vl"
  "cliente_titulo" => "teste name"
  "cliente_data" => "2021/12"
  "cliente_cliente" => "Test"
  "cliente_condominio" => "Test"
]
```

**I can't get the uploaded file**

Where am i going wrong

Answer (score 0):

You get your file object under the request files method.

`$request->files();` or `$request->file();`

For Krajee Request look like below

```
$("#file-1").fileinput({
            theme: 'fa',
            uploadUrl: '{{ url }}',
            showUpload: true,
            uploadAsync: false,
            uploadExtraData: function () {
                return {
                    _token: $("input[name='_token']").val()
                };
            },
            maxFileSize: 3000000,
        });
```

Comment: $request->files() , return: Method files does not exist. $request->file(), return: empty array : []

Comment: I added a sample krajee ajax call above please take look at that.

Comment: I'm going to test this code, a question what is 'directory_select'

Comment: leave the directory_select. I just copy-pasted it from the my codebase.

Comment: $request->files(); or $request->file();

return -> []

and 

$request->all();

return-> "_token" => "x7c454......."